# distinguishing gradients of samples in semi supervised learning under mixup

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, differential-privacy

I'm having trouble drawing conclusions from a specific semi supervised machine learning setting. My use case would be using mixup [Zhang2017] and label guessing similar to the mixmatch paper [Berthelot2019]. That being said, lets say my training data would be split in two sets $T_1,T_2$, for which I have labels for $T_1$ but not for $T_2$ (semi supervised). I perform label guessing on clean samples while performing the forward pass on mixed-inputs and mixed-labels (from data or label guesses respectively). However, I only use cross entropy loss (no special semi supervised loss fn on unlabeled data) for simplicity.

Now, what I like to do is look into a specific layer $k$ of my ML model. Given, a sample drawn $t \in T_1$ from the labeled data, the gradient would be something like $\Delta_{\theta_k}l(M(\tilde t ), \tilde y_t)$ (gradient of the layer with mixup sample $\tilde t$ and mixup label $\tilde y_t$ respectively).  On the other hand, a sample $\neg t \in T_2$ shall be draw from the unlabeled data. This requires me to compute a label guess $y^* = M(\neg t)$ by model forward pass and then calculate the gradient as usual $\Delta_{\theta_k}l(M(\tilde {\neg t}), \tilde {y^*})$ over mixup input and mixup guessed label. My intuition says that observing the gradient should reveal the set membership of a sample being in $T_1$ or $T_2$ to some degree (assuming one only knows how the input is mixup but not the label or label guess) since the "error from label guessing" would be "smaller" than actually having labels. However, there is some degree of uncertainty to the guessing too since the labels are mixup again!

How would one approach to quantify this even further? I feel like this goes into the Privacy research domain but have not found a good lead in term of literature that can help me.

Excuse the bad notation.

```
[Zhang2017] https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09412
[Berthelot2019] https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.02249
```